# Play2 - validation of dynamic part of route(s)

Tags: scala, validation, routes, playframework-2.0

I'm building an API, that takes in a variable path parameter, or dynamic part of the route, as the play documentation would specify it.

I would like to validate this as to give the client a proper response.

I have the following route setup

`GET    /:dynamic/all    controller.method(dynamic: String)`

The `dynamic` param for the method is used across the API, for multiple methods, so i would like to get some kind of global validation/whitelist of acceptable strings. (eg: `"hello"/"hi"` would be accepted, and `"noooway"` would not be accepted, and i would return a `404 not found` as response.

I would preferably like my controller method to not contain any validation so that this would be true:

```
def method(dynamic: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { _ =>
    //I already know "dynamic" is valid here.
    Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "OK"))))
}
```

Instead of: (excuse my javaisc-psuedo-code)

```
def method(dynamic: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { _ =>
    val valid = Helper.validate(dynamic)
    if (!valid) return some result/response else 
    Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "OK"))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play allows you to do this by different ways.

**1. PathBindable**

You can implement a `PathBindable[T]` for any type `T`, so that your value extracted from the path of the request is not a simple `String` but a `T`.

If you are ready to change the type of `dynamic` (which would make sense, since it is not supposed to be just any string but a valid one), you could do the following:

```
case class Validated(str: String) {
  assert(Helper.validate(str))
}

object Validated {
  implicit val pathBindable = new PathBindable[Validated] {
    val string = implicitly[PathBindable[String]]
    override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, Validated] = 
      string.bind(key, value).                                           // bind as if it were a string
        right.filter(Helper.validate).getOrElse(Left("Invalid input")).  // filter using your validation function, and give error message
        right.map(Validated(_))                                          // encapsulate in your new type

    override def unbind(key: String, value: Validated): String =
      string.unbind(key, value.str)  //unbind as if it were a string
  }
}
```

Note that you need to implement `unbind` for reverse routing (get a path for a given action call).

Now, you just need to replace `String` in your router and in your controller by `your.package.Validated`.

```
GET    /:dynamic/all    controller.method(dynamic: your.package.Validated)
```

**NB**: if you want to use the simple name of your class, you need to import it in your `build.sbt`:

```
(project in file(".").
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  settings(routesImport += "your.package.Validated")
```

**2. Action Composition**

You can also implement an action filter to be used whenever your input needs to be validated:

```
case class ValidatedAction(input: String) extends ActionFilter[Request] {
  override protected def filter[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Option[Result]] = Future.successful{
    if (Helper.validate(input)) None else Some(BadRequest("Invalid input"))
  }
}

def method(dynamic: String) = (Action andThen ValidatedAction(dynamic)).async {
  Future.successful(Ok)
}
```

The code inside the `async` block will be executed only if the `filter` method returns `None`, otherwise, it will return the specified `Result` (here, `BadRequest("Invalid input")`.

Comment: Ahh yes - thanks alot. I completely forgot to think about using an `ActionFilter` to do this kind of validation. This seems like a pretty good solution to me. Also props for the `PathBindable` solution aswell. I'm pretty sure i'm gonna need that too, sooner or later.